# Preventing "already defined" error for class implementation in header file

Tags: c++

I want to include the definition and implementation of a C++ class in a header file.

I'm creating a library that need to be C-compatible. The .h file defines a C++ class that can be subclassed for easy C++-style access to the library. It is internally used in the library as well.

As the header file is imported into several subclasses, I always get the "multiple definition" error. Because the class definition should be importable for users of the library, I do not want to move the implementation in a separate cpp file.

Do you have any idea how this problem can be solved?

simplified example:

```
//library:
typedef struct IFoo{
 virtual void foo = 0;
};

void library_fun_a(IFoo*);
void library_fun_b(IFoo*);

//header file
#pragma once
class FooWrapper : public IFoo{
  virtual void foo() override;
};
void FooWrapper::foo(){
  //some magic here
}
```

[Edit] Using include guards doesn't help to stop the compile from including the implementation in all object files and therefore the linker to encounter the "multiple definition" error.

Comment: Did you miss to provide [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your header files?

Comment: If you create a library, it'll normally consist of .h files and the implementation as a lib* containing the .o files. Thus, there's no point in trying to avoid separate .c or .cpp files.

Comment: Why are you providing the implementation this way, instead of inlining it with the declaration? Otherwise separate the implementation out to an extra compilation unit (as usual).

Comment: @laune the definition need to exist as source code in order to include it when compiling the client code

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Multiple *definitions*

Comment: Then you aren't creating a library.

Comment: @laune The library only contains the implementation for `library_fun_a` and `library_fun_b` as well as the definition for `IFoo`. I want to provide an optional helper class, that can be used as a wrapper but is not needed in order to use the library. If the library is consumed with pure C, the class cannot be used anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily solve your multiple defintion problem when you inline your code correctly:

```
class FooWrapper : public IFoo {
    virtual void foo() override {
      //some magic here
    }
};
```

Comment: Of course, if `foo` is non-trivial, you don't want to load up the class definition with its definition.  (You can still make it inline, however, just by providing an out of class definition, and declaring that inline.)

Answer (score 2):

You must use **[include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)** which are essentially just macros that determine if the compiler has already included the interface or whatever contents are in the header file.

For example

```
#ifndef FOO_WRAPPER_H
#define FOO_WRAPPER_H

// header contents here ...

#endif // !FOO_WRAPPER_H
```

If you're using a Microsoft compiler, you can use the directive `#pragma once` at the top of the header file. Note that this breaks compatibility with other compilers.

Comment: thanks but that won't be enough (I'm using header guards) as the implementation will be included in all object files that use the header

Comment: @muffel If you have inlined implementations this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Putting the source in a header file defeats the purpose of headers entirely (with the exception of templated code).